# Packet tracer. Can I have multiple sites on the same web server?

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer

so I have this simple network containing one pc and one web server that contains a site:

[image]

I can access a site hosted on the server from the pc using a web browser, however, I want to access two sites, I tried but I couldn't host another site on the same server, so I added another server to host the second site, like this:

[image]

However, what if I have a 100 sites, making a server for each one doesn't seem realistic.

So my Question is: **How can I host multiple sites on the same server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common implementation with web servers, if you take a look at Apache which is extremely common to be used as a web server you can create a virtual host. You would normally specify a hostname that relates to the directory of the website on the server.

So if you wanted to configure 3 websites on a single server for 3 separate customers, the idea behind it would be something like:

```
companyA.com points to /var/www/companyA
companyB.com points to /var/www/companyB
companyC.com points to /var/www/companyC
```

I would look into some web servers such as Apache and Nginx if you would like to lab the concept on a virtual machine which could be fun and very educational!

Comment: It's also called host header redirection.

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Too many names for the same thing in this world... ;)

Comment: Yep. Just wanted to point it out in case the OP was having a hard time figuring out what else it may be called.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! In packet tracers it's not possible to add multiple sites in single server , because packet tracer is a education tool from networking learners high end features are not available in packet tracer

But in real world it's possible to host multiple applications in single servers

Application can host  in single server with various service ports

Application can hosted in server on port based , name based , ip address based .